# What happens to psykers when a black ship doesn't collect them?

Tags: lore, warhammer-40k

Allegedly a planet is only visited by a black ship once every 100 years or so.

So what happens to psykers found when there is no ship slated to come by anytime soon? After all, they can't just let a psyker run free for 90 years waiting for the next black ship to visit.

Is there any official lore explanation to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this page: https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Sanctioned_Psyker there are other channels in place to hand over psykers who are discovered when a black ship isn't present. The inquisition, arbites etc. can arrange transport to Holy Terra.